# Is there a way to reference characters within an XML element

Tags: xml

I have a XML document with a document structure with the elements chapter, paragraph, article, section, subsection. I want to provide meaning to partial text within these elements.

For example a section text might read "A building within the referenced area may no not be higher than 25m.". I want to reference the "25" and assign it the meaning "max building height" so it is machine interpretable. I could do this by adding XML elements within the text. For example:

```
<text>A building within the referenced area may no not be higher than <meaning type="max building height">25</meaning>m.</text>
```

I would prefer to keep meaning separate from the text and if possible the original XML document. Is it possible to reference a partial text within an element of another XML document?

Example source document:

```
<document>
    <chapter id="5"><text>Building regulations</text>
        <article id="102"><text>Build</text>
            <section id="1a">
                <text>A building within the referenced area may no not be higher than 25m.</text>
            </section>
        </article>
    </chapter>
</document>
```

Example meaning document:

```
<meaning>
    <reference type="max building height" ref="..." start="..." end="..." />
</meaning>
```

Comment: Can you maybe attach a snippet of your document?

Comment: Added an simplified example.

Comment: I don't understand, you quote a text "A building within the referenced area may no not be higher than 25m" and then say 'I want to reference the "10"', there is no `10` in that quoted text.

Comment: Extracting data from text is not a good idea in any language (unless you have not other options of course).  Does chapter 5 / artikel 102/ section 1a of the bulding regulations already imply the max building height?  If it does, then build your logic around those instead.

Comment: @MartinHonnen sorry my mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: The short answer is "XML has nothing like that", the longer answer is "It's a database, you could define a way to reference it using whatever factors you like just so long as you built a tool that could understand what means to reference it"

Comment: @PhilBlackburn I have adjusted all the examples. If I understand correctly you advise against referencing text within elements without an anchor element. I need to have an anchor to identify the characters I want to provide meaning to (see 1st example). Do you have any suggestions how I can keep these anchors separate from the text?

Comment: @Quentin please see my question to Phil Blackburn.

Comment: No, I'm merely guessing at your reasons for referencing the 25 in the first place and suggesting an alterative approach. I normally would not query the design reason why OPs pose some questions but in my experience of Bldg Regs they are are strict and the max height is surely implicit from the article/section id's.  Text is fluid, it can be easily misinterpreted, re-edit, (eg, your example has a grammer error).  Sure, it it possible to locate the position of the numeric digits but to convert human readable text into machine readable data *with context* is big ask of any programming language.

Comment: If you want someone to assist further with this question, you'll need to let us know which version of xsl are you using: xslt-1 or xslt-2

Comment: Hi @PhilBlackburn we are using XSLT 2.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier comments about extracting the values with contextual meaning from text strings still applies but here are a couple of examples that may help you out,

My (preferred) method is based on that fact that for Building Regualtions are typically precisely defined and the max height ought to be known from the chapter/article/section ids.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="chapter[@id='5']/article[@id='102']/section[@id='1a']/text">
<text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'25')"/>
    <meaning type="max building height">25</meaning>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'25')"/>
</text>
</xsl:template>
```

If you dont know the max height is "25", and need to extract it.

This version is not perfect (since extracting numbers from strings is not simple!). For example, If you need to extract a number with a fractional part (say, 12.5) then this method requires more work because, as we all know, the period (.) is also use to end a sentence.
There are many other cases that can break it.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
<text>
    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="fn:tokenize(.,' ')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$tokens">
        <xsl:variable name="v" select="fn:translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.','')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string(number($v)) != 'NaN' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,$v)"/>
                <meaning type="max building height"><xsl:value-of select="$v"/></meaning>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,$v)"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>          
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @PhilpBlackburn I agree with you that this is going to become to much of a guessing game and therefor to complex. Back to the drawing board :-) Thx for your help.